# Asp.Net datagridview: Where clause is not functioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Here is my `DataGridView` design code:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [CNAME] FROM [Registration] WHERE ([USERNAME] = @USERNAME)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="USERNAME" SessionField="username" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["username"] = "1";
            }

         }
```

The program is running but there is no output after logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QueryString` instead of `Session`

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT [CNAME] FROM [Registration] WHERE ([USERNAME] = @USERNAME)">
        <SelectParameters>
 <asp:querystringparameter name="USERNAME" type="String" querystringfield="username" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: after i changed to query string parameter..still the same output. the program is running but no output once logged in

Comment: then you should check your table that is there any id has value "1"? OR Is the USERNAME is the field cantoning the value "1", it can be the issue of wrong column name.

Comment: sorry..im new to asp.net..i dont know how to check whether the id has a value of 1 or not?

Comment: open your database and open your table then check the field "USERNAME" has the value of "1" or not. Please provide your whole code so that I can check the issue.

Comment: I have add value 1 in default value or binding for username. but still no effect. You want me to copy paste all the codings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code(but i guess i got my tables values wrong )

```
namespace IncendoVentures


        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            Label_welcome.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["username"] = 1;
        }


    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Uploads.aspx");
    }





    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx");
    }

    protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
    }



}
```

}

The design code:

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
        style="color: #000000; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: underline; font-size: x-large" 
        Text="SELECT COMPANY"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"


        SelectCommand="SELECT [CNAME] FROM [Registration] WHERE ([USERNAME] = @USERNAME)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="USERNAME" SessionField="username" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 

        BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
        CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" 
        style="font-size: large; margin-right: 0px;" Width="647px" AllowPaging="True" 

        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">

        <RowStyle BackColor="White" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CNAME" HeaderText="CNAME" 
                SortExpression="CNAME" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: your code seems right, I think problem is of your table's value or also check your connection string in Web.Config file that connection to your database is right or wrong.

Comment: and one thing more, never post your comments in the 'Answer' whether it contains any code or not.

Comment: when i set the default value or binding for Username field to 1..once saved its converted to ((1)) automatically. My Web.Config file shows the correct connection with my database name.